# PICTURED - What causes this sort of clearing?

Tags: forests, pennsylvania

I have been to several locations where I have seen clearing similar to the one I am in currently? This was a clear cut logging area. There are what look like small trees that we cut down, though this was identified in the answer below as the branches removed from the trunks, and left behind.

Location: Southern Pennsylvania - Fort Loudon.

Photos are from August 16th, 2016

These are my personal photos and require no licensing. Feel free to use and share.

[image: Clearing - view 1]

[image: Clearing - view 2]

[image: Trimmed branches - trunk had been removed in clear cutting process]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is cause by clearcut timber harvesting. Timber harvesters will remove branches from trees that they fell and leave them on site. They will also sometimes leave specimen trees to help repopulate the area - or leave undesirable individual trees or species. The standing trees might also be the result of a weak implementation of a [clearcut with reserve](https://www.for.gov.bc.ca/hre/stems/clearcut.htm).

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OP might miss that what they are calling cut down regrowth you are recognizing as branches trimmed off during the harvest.

Comment: @JamesJenkins You are absolutely correct, I had forgotten my OP said that the branches left behind looked like regrowth or small tree trunks. Edited, thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. A park ranger confirmed that this land was used as in a timber sale (clear cut logging) in 2014 - 2015. The current growth is 1 year old. This land is also now a help to bolster a local bird population providing new sources of wild blueberry bushes (he said he also calls them Huckleberry bushes)

Comment: Glad I could help. Now ID the berry bushes - blueberries and huckleberries are two different things.